# Instance reachability check failed on ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I was uploading my laravel project changes and deleting file from folders with this command `sudo rm *` on ec2 instance at the same time it stops responding. Now I can't logedin through putty . it gets time out when I try to connect through ssh. When I see status check it is giving this error. Instance reachability check failed on ec2 instance

Comment: Looks like you deleted a system folder.

Comment: I also think that how i could repair that?

Comment: You can't. You will need to restore from an ami you have taken of the instance or use a marketplace image from scratch.

Comment: what is AMI? is it kind of backup?

Comment: An image taken of the instance. If you don't know what it is, you will most probably need to start from scratch.

Comment: OMG you mean i need to deploy project again?

Comment: can I copy setting of instance to new instance?

Comment: You can create an ami (image) of the existing instance but that will be pointless if the existing instance doesn't boot.

Comment: ok thanks . i am creating new instance